# socat resetting USB port on open

Tags: tcp, serial-port, socat

I'm having an issue with socat, and it is probably just in my environment.

I need to have a USB serial port redirected to a TCP port. I use the following and it works perfectly:

`socat TCP-LISTEN:4444,fork,reuseaddr FILE:/dev/ttyUSB0,b19200,rawer`

However, the problem with the above is that every time I connect to a port 4444, I get the USB port reset, which resets the USB device. I kind of think it is as per design, that USB0 port is not held open the moment you start socat, but only when someone connects to port 4444. Does anyone know how to make socat open the USB port on start (not when someone connects), and not to close after someone disconnects?

Answer (score 0):

What you try is opening the tty in the shell script just before the socat command so that when socat open and closes it later, there will still be one open use, so it should not reset. Simply add, for example,

```
exec 5</dev/ttyUSB0
```

This opens the device as file descriptor 5 for the rest of the script.